# 3 mass spring collision

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, collision, spring

[image]

---

A small ball with mass $M$ moves along a horizontal smooth table with velocity $v_0$. It hits the system of two balls with masses $m$ and $2m$ with attached spring between them as shown in the picture. What is the maximum ratio $\alpha = m/M$, when the balls will collide one more time. Assume that collisions between the balls are perfectly elastic.

---

I'm not sure where to get started, but I don't want a full solution just yet. what i'm looking for is a concept on where to start this problem, i.e. momentum conservation, or energy, or something else.

Comment: Greetings! Please don’t edit your question in a way that invalidates existing answers; it’s not respectful towards the other users who have put in effort trying to help you.

Comment: oh sorry, will do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried it but this would be my first attempt.

For starters, forget that $m$ is attached to $2m$ and focus on the collision between $M$ and $m$. You should be able to compute the velocities of $M$ and $m$ instantaneously after the collision using conservation of momentum and energy. Once you have these, you can now focus on the motion of the spring system right after the collision. The key is two separate the motion of $m$ and $2m$ into the motion of their center of mass and their relative motion. The motion of the center of mass is very simple: it moves at constant velocity. You should be able to compute this velocity from the velocity of $m$ right after the impact. The relative motion will be that of a single body attached to the spring with mass equal to the reduced mass $(m\times 2m)/(m+2m)=2m/3$. After you have solved for its motion you can return to the original problem and reinterpret your results in term of the motion for $m$. You can then check whether $M$ and $m$ touch each other again.